# SAP UI5 fragment with timeline

Tags: dialog, sapui5, timeline

i am trying to create a ui5 app where i need to open a dialogue containing a timeline on a button click.

My problem is concerning the height of the dialogue which always looks like the below .  [image]

only if i drag the dialogue i see the remaining entries in the timeline.

The width sets fine but the height does not even though i am setting is explicitly. Any ideas on how to expand the height of the timeline so that it fits correctly in the dialog?.

As per the documentation of a sap.m.Dialog:

If the contentWidth and/or contentHeight properties are set, the dialog will try to fill those sizes.
If there is no specific sizing, the dialog will try to adjust its size to its content.

PS: I am using a fragment as i need to resue the timeline.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:c="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
   <Dialog title="Change Log" showHeader="true" draggable="true">
        <c:Timeline height="100rem" width="30rem" enableDoubleSided="true" 
          groupBy="{XYZ}" 
             growingThreshold="10" filterTitle="Title" sortOldestFirst="false" 
               content="{changes}" showIcons="false" icon="sap-icon://edit">
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<Dialog title="Change Log" showHeader="true" draggable="true" contentHeight="25rem">
```

Use `contentHeight` property to set height to the dialog.

> I don't know whether the below solution can be used because it is
>   overriding the standard CSS library.

**Feel free to update the answer if someone has a better solution regarding this.**

```
.sapMDialog>.sapMDialogSection {
    min-height: 25rem;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to set the enableScroll attribute of the Timeline to false to get the full height of the timeline in the dialog.

```
<core:FragmentDefinition xmlns="sap.ui.commons" xmlns:c="sap.suite.ui.commons" xmlns:m="sap.m" xmlns:core="sap.ui.core">
   <Dialog title="Change Log" showHeader="true" draggable="true">
        <c:Timeline enableScroll="false" height="100rem" width="30rem" enableDoubleSided="true" 
          groupBy="{XYZ}" 
             growingThreshold="10" filterTitle="Title" sortOldestFirst="false" 
               content="{changes}" showIcons="false" icon="sap-icon://edit">
```